# Alocação e limpeza de memória em C - o quanto devo me preocupar?

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, memória, garbage-collector

Estou aprendendo C pelo livro "Use a Cabeça! C" (me condenem).
Dada uma lição, eu preciso criar uma `struct` chamada "**island**" com o seguinte código:

```
typedef struct island {
    const char *name;
    const char *opens;
    const char *closes;
    struct island *next;
} island;
```

Após uma série de mudanças que sigo no livro, chega a hora de escrever um método para criar uma `island`, alocando memória dinamicamente com `malloc` para então, retornar o ponteiro do objeto criado. Abaixo o código dessa função:

```
island* create(char *name)
{
    island *i = malloc(sizeof(island));
    i->name = strdup(name);
    i->opens = "09:00";
    i->closes = "17:00";
    i->next = NULL;

   return i;
}
```

Por fim, e onde está o meu problema, o livro guia você a liberar a memória que você alocou para não deixa-la com "lixo", utilizando um método `release`:

```
void release(island *start)
{
    island *i = start;
    island *next = NULL;
    for(; i != NULL; i = next) {
        next = i->next;
        free(i->name);
        free(i);
    }
}
```

Ao tentar passar uma `struct` para essa função, eu recebo os erros a seguir:

```
memoriaDinamica.c: In function ‘release’:
memoriaDinamica.c:83:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘free’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
         free(i->name);
              ^
In file included from memoriaDinamica.c:2:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:483:13: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
             ^
*** Error in `./memoriaDinamica': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400940 ***
Name: Amity open: 09:00-17:00
Name: Craggy open: 09:00-17:00
Name: Isla Nublar open: 09:00-17:00
Name: Skull open: 09:00-17:00

The newly created island:
Name: Hawaii open: 09:00-17:00
Name: Skull open: 09:00-17:00
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x77a8d)[0x7fee806c1a8d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x5cd)[0x7fee806cdd2d]
./memoriaDinamica[0x400886]
./memoriaDinamica[0x400791]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fee8066a700]
./memoriaDinamica[0x400589]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 2097225                            memoria-dinamica/memoriaDinamica
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 fd:02 2097225                            memoria-dinamica/memoriaDinamica
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 fd:02 2097225                            memoria-dinamica/memoriaDinamica
02248000-02269000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fee80433000-7fee80449000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1049963                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-5.1.1-20150618.so.1
7fee80449000-7fee80648000 ---p 00016000 fd:01 1049963                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-5.1.1-20150618.so.1
7fee80648000-7fee80649000 r--p 00015000 fd:01 1049963                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-5.1.1-20150618.so.1
7fee80649000-7fee8064a000 rw-p 00016000 fd:01 1049963                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-5.1.1-20150618.so.1
7fee8064a000-7fee80801000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1054187                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.21.so
7fee80801000-7fee80a00000 ---p 001b7000 fd:01 1054187                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.21.so
7fee80a00000-7fee80a04000 r--p 001b6000 fd:01 1054187                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.21.so
7fee80a04000-7fee80a06000 rw-p 001ba000 fd:01 1054187                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.21.so
7fee80a06000-7fee80a0a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fee80a0a000-7fee80a2b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1054235                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.21.so
7fee80c05000-7fee80c08000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fee80c27000-7fee80c2a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fee80c2a000-7fee80c2b000 r--p 00020000 fd:01 1054235                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.21.so
7fee80c2b000-7fee80c2c000 rw-p 00021000 fd:01 1054235                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.21.so
7fee80c2c000-7fee80c2d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffc4d52b000-7ffc4d54c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc4d550000-7ffc4d552000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc4d552000-7ffc4d554000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
/bin/sh: line 1: 23871 Abortado                (imagem do núcleo gravada)./memoriaDinamica
```

Eu entendo que uma referência para uma constante não pode ser liberada por motivos óbvios, sendo assim, eu realmente devo me preocupar com a limpeza dessa memória alocada em casos como o desse exemplo?

[Código completo no Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wGkccYtc)

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Você deve se preocupar já que a função `strdup()` (seria melhor usar [`strndup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)) aloca memória no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Toda memória alocada no *heap* deve ser liberada.

C não tem *garbage collector* e todo gerenciamento de memória deve ser feito manualmente. Claro que pode-se criar algumas funções para ajudar, mas conforme vai sofisticando isto e vai automatizando está criando algum tipo de GC para sua aplicação.

Algumas funções podem fazer um pouco este tipo de serviço. É o caso da `strndupa()`. Ela não é padronizada e portanto não portátil. Ela não resolve todas situações.

A solução de fato é tirar o `const`, afinal algo que será alocado no *heap* não é constante.

Se quiser insistir nisto, faça um *cast*:

```
free((char *)i.name);
```

ou

```
free((void *)i.name);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Cast.c).

Não vou te garantir que funciona com todas opções de compilação. Aí a solução seria desligar o *warning*, o que eu não recomendo.

Comment: Entendi @bigown. Depois que removi `const` da `struct` ele me retorna o erro `Error in \`./memoriaDinamica': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400940`. Esse erro se repete mesmo se eu faço *cast*. Eu sei que o problema é que o ponteiro é inválido. Talvez não esteja entendendo como referenciar o atributo *name* para ser liberado.

Comment: Eu mudei o operador que está errado, nem parei pra pensar nisto. Você tem que pegar o ponteiro e não o valor. Essas coisas q postou agora eu teria que analisar, mas não agora, vou dormir :) Eu acho que não é isso.